# Adaptive UI UWP

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, adaptive-ui

I am trying to learn about adaptive UI. I use bootstrap alot, but am in the process of designing a Windows 10 app with `xaml`. I am wanting the `textboxes` and `textbloxks` to adjust based on if the user shrinks the window or not. This is what I have, but it is not `adapting` nor is it responsive.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="24" Margin="10,22,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Title" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxTitle" Margin="79,24,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Width="800" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="24" Margin="10,131,0,0" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Body" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxBody" Margin="79,133,-225,0" Grid.Row="1" Width="800" Height="500" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnSubmitArticle" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Margin="80,20,20,20" d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
    </Grid>
```

**Additional Question**

How can I pull the text in the textbox all the way to the right of the window and have it respond correctly when the screen size changes.

```
<RelativePanel Margin="12,12">
           <TextBlock x:Name="txtBoxDate"
           RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
           RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
           FontSize="14" 
           TextAlignment="Right"
           TextWrapping="Wrap" 
           Text="Title" />
</RelativePanel>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to making these elements repsonsive depending on screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the whole row stretches, the problem is that you're setting Width of those elements (and some weird Margins, probably because you dragged and dropped the controls from the toolbox). You can use a RelativePanel to nicely stack the items and keep them stretched from left to right inside the panel:

```
<RelativePanel Margin="12,0">
    <TextBlock x:Name="FirstTextBlock"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
               RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
               FontSize="24" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Title" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxTitle" 
             RelativePanel.Below="FirstTextBlock"
             RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
             Margin="0,8,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="SecondTextBlock" 
               RelativePanel.Below="txtBoxTitle"
               RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
               RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
               FontSize="24" 
               Margin="0,8,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" 
               Text="Body" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtBoxBody" 
             RelativePanel.Below="SecondTextBlock"
             RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
             RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
             Margin="0,8,0,0" 
             Height="500" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             AcceptsReturn="True" />
    <Button x:Name="btnSubmitArticle" 
            RelativePanel.Below="txtBoxBody"
            Content="Submit" 
            Margin="0,8,0,0" 
            d:LayoutOverrides="Width"/>
</RelativePanel>
```

Comment: I see this is kind of doing what I am looking for it to... Can you explain a little further as to how this works? I am very similar to Bootstrap, so if you want to compare it to that....

Comment: is there a way for me to set the relative panel to right side of window? Other than the margin?

Comment: @Code can you then do it with Bootstrap and attach a screenshot to clarify what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just want to pull the textblock to the right, so <textbox style="pull-right;"/>

Comment: @Code set TextAlignment to Right. TextAlignment="Right".